# Teradata BTET from Informtica

Tags: teradata, informatica

I have a requirement to call Teradata BTET from Informatica .
can any one tell me that if I create a flow ( in one single mapping ) with a ---

--dummy talble as source and target and write into its pre-sql:

begin transaction;

lock A for write;

--after this I create a my flow of mapping where I will insert data in A table

--then in last I have a flow with same dummy table whose post-sql has command

end transaction;

will this work?

Comment: simply I need to create a transaction and need a write lock on table

Comment: Why do you need to create dummy flows? You can write pre-SQL and pos t-SQL for the main flow itself.

Comment: no pre-post SQL fires commit implicitly so they will unlock the table , its of no use